# How to return from a CSV file

Tags: scala, csv

I am reading a csv file.

Edit: Symbol is a stock and I need to make a function reads the corresponding CSV‑file and returns the list of strings that start with the given year. e.g the value of that stock at the given year.

Each line in the CSV is in the form

```
year‐01‐day,somePrice
e.g 1980-01-02,5.512945
```

Expected output should be

```
scala> getdata("S", 1980)
res1: List[String] = List(
    1980-01-02,5.512945, 
    1980-01-03,5.601156, 
    1980-01-04,5.590126, 
    1980-01-07,5.568071,
    1980-01-08,5.942955,
    ...
```

)

The output I get

```
 scala> getdata("S", 1980)
 res1: List[String] = List(
     1980-01-02, 
     1980-01-03, 
     1980-01-04, 
     1980-01-07, 
     1980-01-08,
     ...
 )
```

As you can see I am missing the somePrice, I do not know why this is as I split each line

My code

```
 def getdata(symbol: String, year: Int) : List[String] = {
     val a = for(
        b <- Source.fromFile("someFile.csv").getLines.toList
     ) yield b.split("\n").toList.filter(_.startsWith(year.toString)) 
     a.flatten
}
```

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: `symbol:String` is never used and serves no purpose. In `getLines.toList` the `.toList` serves no purpose. `b.split(\n)` doesn't do anything because `getLines` strips all `\n` out.

Comment: How can I use the **symbol:String** in my code to get it too work?

Comment: Your question doesn't say _how_ `symbol` is supposed to be used. It also lacks an example of file contents. Hard to get expected output without example input.

Comment: Example input has been shown above, `scala> getdata("S", 1980)`.

Comment: @jwvh I have edited the question to make it abit more clear.

Comment: You've provided an input _description_: `year‐01‐day,somePrice`. That's not the same as some input _examples_. And you still haven't described _how_ `symbol` is supposed to be used. Is `"S"` found somewhere in the input file's content? Is it supposed to be a part of the filename and thus used to select the correct file? From what you've posted there's still a lot of guesswork. And, FWIW, I ran your code on dummy input and got the "expected" results.

Comment: @jwvh "S" is a company. This companies stock information is stored inside the csv file ("somefile.csv"). We want to return "S's" stock price for only the given year.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the file? What you've provided so far doesn't actually show _how_ the company symbol e.g. `S` is connected to the year and price data. Is there another column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing the for () yield, normally the filter should be on top

```
for(x <- c; if cond) yield {...}
```

See : https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

However, your code did work for me, but you have to split("\n")

```
def getdata(symbol: String, year: Int): List[String] = {
  Source.fromFile("someFile.csv")
    .getLines
    .filter(line => line.startsWith(year.toString)).toList
}
```

getLines-> will split on lines 
then on yield you also do b.split("\n")